# Unable to define a variable in Vue using the composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api

I'm coding a Vue app for my first project ever. I'm using json-server as simulating server waiting to learn how Firebase works later.
At some point I get to fetch some data and find an object by id property through the array of data I fetched to get another proprety from it. The problem is that the object stays undefined, can't understand how. I'm using the composition API:

```
export default {
  props: ['id'],
    setup(props) {
    const caregivers = ref([]);
    const caregiverById = ref(null);
    const error = ref('');

    onMounted(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/caregivers');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('No available data');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        caregivers.value = data;                  
        console.log(caregivers.value);

        // Find the caregiver by ID
        caregiverById.value = caregivers.value.find((caregiver) => caregiver.id === props.id);
        console.log('caregiverById:');
        console.log(caregiverById.value);
      } catch (err) {
        error.value = err.message;
        console.log(error.value);
      }
    });

    return { caregivers, caregiverById, error };
}
}
```

The console.log returns `caregiverById.value` still undefined while `caregivers.value` is defined and  returns an array as expected while the props seems to be fine too and well passed:

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrc1.png)

Funny enough I tried to rewrite everything with no composition API with a simple .fetch() method and... it works, logging the right object, so I'm sure that and object with that id passed as props always exists in the `caregivers`.
Written like this everything works fine:

```
export default {
    props: [ 'id' ],
    components: { EvaluationCard },
    data() {
      return {
        caregivers: [],
        caregiverById: [],
        error: '',
          }
    },
    mounted() {
        
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/caregivers')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => this.caregivers = data)
        .then(() => console.log(this.caregivers))
        .then(() => this.caregiverById = this.caregivers.find((caregiver) => caregiver.id = this.id))
        .then(() => console.log(this.caregiverById))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
}
}
```

Why it doesn't work with the composition API? I'm missing something?

Comment: did you define the props in your composition API code? you didn't show.  what is the value of `props.id` in your setup function?  FYI there are two ways to write composition API components, and most people prefer the newer, simpler [script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) syntax.

Comment: Yes I defined the props. I can console.log "props.id" and it returns me a number, in this case "1". Also, thank you for the suggestion about script setup, I will check it out later.

Comment: Can you include your props definition and the logs of `console.log(caregivers.value)` and `console.log(props.id)` in your question? If caregivers and props.id are both defined it must be something wrong with the `find` function. looking at the exact data returned by the logs should reveal why. Do the types match? e.g. `1 === '1'` is false.

Comment: I included the image with the logs. Props seems to be fine, it's just that find method that doesn't work somehow.

Comment: I can see from the warning the component is written like `<EvaluationsList id="1">`.  This syntax would pass down a string value of `"1"`.  That might be your issue.  If you want a **number** value of `1` use [v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind), e.g.  `<EvaluationsList :id="1">`.

Comment: I don't know why it gets shown like that in the warning, but actually in the parent component there is written ```<EvaluationsList :id="1">```  Anyway the warning doesn't show anymore after I removed something in the template which was looping through a non existent "evaluations" array yet, which I was supposed to fetch after the caregivers one.